# How to expand hash into argument list in function call in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax

How to expand hash into argument list in function call in Perl? I am searching Perl equivalent of Python's syntax : `somefunc(**somedict)` or `somefunc(*somelist)`. Is that possible in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, all function arguments are passed as lists and stored in the special array variable `@_`. You can copy those values to some other array, or directly into a hash (as you can with any array/list).

If you are writing a function, you can pass the arguments directly into an array or hash:

```
sub hashFunc {
    my %args = @_;

    ....
}

sub arrayFunc {
    my @args = @_;

    ...
}
```

To call a function like that, just pass them as if they were a list or hash:

```
hashFunc(arg1 => 'someVal', arg2 => 'someOtherVal');
arrayFunc('someVal', 'someOtherVal');
```

If you already have the arguments in a variable, just pass them along and Perl flattens out the array/hash into the argument list:

```
hashFunc(%someHash);
arrayFunc(@someArray);
```

Comment: it's exactly the passing part where i would like to expand hash - to call someFunc(<MYSTERIOUS_OPERAND>%hash) which puts %hash into @_, not @_[0]

Comment: @ts.: you don't need that "mysterious operand", this is the default behaviour of Perl.

Comment: @ts., It's impossible to place `%hash` in `$_[0]`, since array values can only be scalars. (You could place a reference to a hash in an array, but that's a story for another day.)

Comment: Passing a hash by converting it to a list of arguments and then back to a hash inside the function is perfectly fine but not terribly efficient; passing a reference is more efficient.  (That said it's also not what the OP asked for so I'm just adding a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Hashes do expand into a list when calling a function:

```
my %h = (a => 1, b => 2, c => 3);

sub foo {
  # prints the key-value pairs in unsorted order
  print "@_\n";
}

foo %h;
```